# assigning value from select linq query not updating the list

Tags: c#, linq

> query is like this:-

```
   labRequestItem.LabTest.Select(p=>p.LabTestICDCodes= labRequests.ICDCodes.Select(t => new ICDCodeList()
                                    {
                                        ICDCodeId = t.ICDCodeId,
                                        ICDCode = t.ICDCodeName,
                                        ICDDescription = t.ICDDescription,
                                        ICDCodeType = t.ICDCodeType
                                    }).ToArray());
```

Now the issue is that **LabTestICDCodes** is not updating with the new list value returning from select statement

Comment: You're just calling `Select`. That doesn't actually do anything, because LINQ is lazy. It looks like you should really just be doing a `foreach` loop here - LINQ is *not* designed for side-effects like this.

Comment: Possible reason is that query is not enumerated. You can try to call `ToList()` method on the inner Select query

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to update the property from the select statement, i dont want to use the foreach loop. We can do this right? but here  it is not working may be property is not notifying it.

Comment: @Fabjan OP is calling `ToArray`, so that part can be ruled out

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The inner query is not executed as no `.ToArray()` or `ToList()` or foreach loop is called

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use `foreach`? What's the goal? More context please.

Comment: Issue as Jon pointed out is Select is meant for Projection not assignment as you are trying to modify value, where it might be ignoring the assignment, I am surprised no exception, if its a simple `IEnumerator`

Comment: @Fabjan `ToArray() or ToList()` is not there on `outer select not inner select`, which is the possible reason , you have mentioned `inner select`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Oh, you're right, didn't spotted that parenthesis at the end. But it's the same thing though

Comment: Also I assume, you collect the result of Select in a separate variable and checking the modification, you don't expect `labRequestItem.LabTest` changed by this, which would never:

`var finalLabTest = labRequestItem.LabTest.Select ...`

Comment: @Fabjan Agreed that's surely causing deferred execution and results don't materialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in the `Linqpad`, following shall work, but please note:

- `finalResult` would be `List` of `type of LabTestICDCodes` (which is again `IEnumerable` itself) with new / modified values, as that's the only column projected. You have to project the whole object you want as a result, values will modify as expected

  ```
  var finalResult =
  labRequestItem.LabTest.Select(p=>p.LabTestICDCodes= labRequests.ICDCodes.Select(t => new ICDCodeList()
                                  {
                                      ICDCodeId = t.ICDCodeId,
                                      ICDCode = t.ICDCodeName,
                                      ICDDescription = t.ICDDescription,
                                      ICDCodeType = t.ICDCodeType
                                  }).ToArray()).ToList();
  ```

Comment: It is working, but I want to know why returning finalResult because no where we are using this.Is it mandatory to write that?

Comment: Please understand the local variable to get the return value of the Extension Method - `Select`, this is like any method, where you collect the return value and work using it, original variable cannot be used for it, until and unless explicit assigned to the result

Answer (score 0):

> I found only way to solve this problem  by doing following step:-
>
> 1.Get the value in local variable

```
 var icdList = labRequests.ICDCodes.Select(t => new ICDCodeList()
                                        {
                                            ICDCodeId = t.ICDCodeId,
                                            ICDCode = t.ICDCodeName,
                                            ICDDescription = t.ICDDescription,
                                            ICDCodeType = t.ICDCodeType
                                        }).ToArray();
```

> 2. Now assign the value by usinf foreach loop.

```
foreach (var test in labRequestItem.LabTest)
                                    {
                                        test.LabTestICDCodes = icdList;
                                    }
```

> In Last step I have to use foreach loop, if any other solution then
>   please reply otherwise I will use the same as it mentioned above.